# invalid ul & li tags in HTML

Tags: html

I am trying [this](http://www.testdome.com/Questions/HtmlCss/Inspector/2347) exercise in HTML. There are 5 test cases and One of them is giving me trouble. I have tried everything but I still couldn't figure out the problem. I just can't pass the 'Lists and images' Test Case. Can anyone help me?

We need to fix the errors in following HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Company page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <paragraph>Welcome! Here you can find following things:</paragraph>
    <ol>
      <em><li><a href="#logo">Company's logo</a></li></em>
      <li><a href="#employees">List of employees</a></li>
    </ol>

    <h2>Company's logo
    <paragraph>Company uses following logos:</paragraph>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="new_logo.gif">New logo</img></li>
      <li><img src="old_logo.gif">Old logo</img></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>List of employees
    <thead>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </thead>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Williams</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my answer

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Company page</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Welcome! Here you can find following things:</p>
<ol>
    <li><a href="#logo">Company's logo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#employees">List of employees</a></li>
</ol>

<h2>Company's logo</h2>

<p>Company uses following logos:</p>

<ol>
    <li><img src="new_logo.gif" alt="new logo">New logo</li>
    <li><img src="old_logo.gif" alt="old logo">Old logo</li>
</ol>

<h2>List of employees</h2>

<table>
    <thead>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Williams</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're missing a doctype.
2. You threw away the `em` tags. I imagine
   you're supposed to just move them.
3. You changed the `ul` to `ol`.
4. Also, `th` is like `td` - it has to be inside of a `tr`.

Comment: shout I wrap the <a> with <em> tag?

Comment: But the Test Case I fail is on 'List & Images' . Not tables.

Comment: Permitted content is phrasing content, which includes the `a` tag. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em.

Comment: Oh, you changed the `ul` to `ol` :p

Comment: Thanks mate. it was actually the <ul> and <em>